# How to ignore subfolders and redirect to the root directory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I'm new in the world of .htaccess and I have a problem. I searched in google how to redirect always to a file, like wordpress do it, and I found this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /demo/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tested this and it works but I want to ignore the subfolders and redirect like it does when you request a folder which doesn't exist. Does anyone how to ignore all the subfolders, and redirect without changing the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the second `RewriteCond` which checks if directory doesn't exist `!-d`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /demo/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```